# In gulp, why do we need to give it a hint to tell it when the task is done?

Tags: gulp

I am really confused with it, when I try to make gulp tasks async.If I give it a hint that the second task depends on completion of the first, I think it's enough. Why do we need to give it a hint to tell it when the first task is done? Is it more easy to tell whether the first task is done? I think it's so redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Gulp knows when a sync function has finished because control is returned to the calling function.

Async functions return control to the calling function *as soon as they have been initiated*.  If you don't tell Gulp when the async function has finished, it has no way of knowing when it is finished.